# How can I add different team members to work on a single project in Botframework compose like adding them as a collaborator

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

Is it possible in Bot framework composer to add collaborators in a project?

Comment: What do you mean by collaborators? Are you talking about people who have permission to edit the project like a LUIS collaborator? Where is your project stored, and what would prevent someone from editing it?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Yes, collaborators like we do in LUIS app. who so ever has access to LUIS Authoring key he/she can make changes in the LUIS app. How I can achieve the same in Bot framework composer.